# UI object created through XML are not being sweeped in Android Marshmallow

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-studio, garbage-collection

I am working on porting android marshmallow for some hardware. The problem I am facing is, if I create a UI object via xml, it is not being sweeped by GC.
For example:

I've created an app to check this.
This app is having 2 activities.
Each activity has a button.
If I press this button, it finishes current activity and starts other activity.

If I define a button in xml layout and in activity setcontentview, it'll create an object of type button. Now I am toggling these activites again and again to create multiple objects of button, since I am not using any LAUNCH_MODE(Intentionally).

Now lets say 8 objects of Button has been created. I pressed back button multiple times and came to home screen. I initiated GC from Android Studio. After that if I take Heap Dump, still I find 8 instances of Button but "ids of objects are changed". Moreover, I saw that constructor of Button class not being called after I initiated GC.

So who created these objects. And if these are same objects, why ids has been changed.

Same thing if I do by creating Button object using Button java class,

like Button b = new Button(Context c);

objects are being sweeped.

Please put some light if you understand the problem.

BR,
Rahul

Comment: Could you share a [mcve]?

Answer (score 0):

You have not provided any code examples for what you are talking about. I can only guess that you are actually creating these Button objects as you mentioned,

```
Button b = new Button(this);
```

If you are referencing a button widget in XML then you should not be creating any Button objects, you should only be instantiating the object.

Button created in XML

```
<Button
   android:id="@+id/btn_action"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Instantiating button in code

```
Button btnAction = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_action);
```

This button object should not have multiple id references. When you assign an id to this widget in XML, the reference id is immediately added to your R.java file. Check your R.java file you will see something like

```
public static final int btn_action=0x7f0d033b;
```

This is a final value, it cannot be changed. So every time you reference the object, btnAction, you are referencing 0x7f0d033b. Destroying your Activity will destroy this object unless you are doing something odd like create static objects.

Also note that there is no guarantee that GC will get called immediately after an Activity is destroyed. It is mostly called when necessary. If you want to help "force" GC to be called when an Activity is destroyed then do clean up in onDestroy() of the Activity. Cheers!

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
   // invoke garbage collector
   System.gc();
}
```

Also keep in mind that calling System.gc() does not necessarily mean Garbage Collector will be called. The definition for this is

> Indicates to the VM that it would be a good time to run the garbage
>   collector. Note that this is a hint only. There is no guarantee that
>   the garbage collector will actually be run.

Comment: Actually I am trying both.

With:
Button b = new Button(this);
Objects of button are being swept once I initiate GC.

With:
XML way
Button objects are not being swept when I am initiating GC.

I understand GC is not guaranteed, but I am initiating it from android monitor, which should sweep all de-referenced objects.

Answer (score 0):

No need to new a Button, the button is already defined in manifest,just using findViewById to look it up.